# Connection between "right" as in a liberty and "right" as in the direction

Tags: etymology, history

I've noticed that it is not only in English that the word "right" can be used both as a noun (when talking about liberty) and an adjective (when talking about direction) It's slso like that in Spanish (derechos/derecha), Portuguese (direitos/direita) and French (droit/droite) What caused this connection between the two "rights" and why?

Comment: Because "left" is sinister.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since ancient times (don't know how ancient) existed the notion that the right hand and the right side were the "correct" ones, as can be seen in the meaning of *sinister* as "evil", from Latin *sinister* meaning "left".
As the [Online Etymology Dictionary says](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=right),

> Other derivations on a similar pattern to English *right* are French
>   *droit*, from Latin *directus* "straight;" Lithuanian *labas*, literally "good;" and Slavic words (Bohemian *pravy*, Polish *prawy*,
>   Russian *pravyj*) from Old Church Slavonic *pravu*, literally
>   "straight" [...]

And, from *right* meaning "correct", the meaning "what is just" or "what (good) is deserved or one's entitled to" follows.

Comment: And "dexter", "dexterous", "ambidextrous".